# How should you correctly encode a large number of blit or scaling commands in Metal?

Tags: macos, metal, metal-performance-shaders

In an application I'm working on that uses a traditional Metal rendering loop, I periodically need to copy a lot of image data from `IOSurfaces` to `MTLTextures` so that the data can be accessed in the fragment shader. I am trying to learn the most effective way to do that.

Each `IOSurface` represents a tile in a potentially very large image. (Like a stitched panorama.) Core Image is used for rendering image data into each `IOSurface`.

In Metal, I have an `MTLTexture` of type `2DArray` that contains enough slices to cover the viewport and/or image itself, if the image is "zoomed out" smaller than the view's size.

The `IOSurface` and `MTLTexture` each of dimensions that are powers-of-two, but they might be different dimensions at times. When they are the same dimension, I use an `MTLBlitCommandEncoder` but when they differ in size I use `MPSImageScale`.

If I need to copy a lot of IOSurface's to a lot of Metal Textures, should I do it one-at-a-time, in batches or all at once?

**Attempt #1: All At Once**

This method works but starts to breakdown if the number of visible surfaces becomes quite large. You end up pre-allocating a bunch of surface-backed textures before committing them. This method seems the most logical to me, but it also causes the most warnings in Xcode's GPU insights and uses up the most texture memory when it doesn't need to.

*Pseudo-code below:*

```
func renderAllAtOnce() { 

  // Create one command buffer. 
  let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()
  let blitEncoder = commandBuffer.makeBlitCommandEncoder()

  // Encode a copy for each surface.
  for surface in visibleSurfaces { 

    // Make a texture from the surface.
    let surfaceTexture = makeTextureFromSurface(surface)

    // Copy from the surface-backed texture into the appropriate slice in the destination texture.
    bitEncoder.copy(surfaceTexture, to: destinationTexture, slice:...)
  }

  // Commit the encoder.
  blitEncoder.endEncoding()
  commandBuffer.commit()
  commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()

  // Bind textures and issue draw calls using a render encoder.
  renderEncoder.draw(...)
}
```

**Attempt 2: In Batches**

In this implementation, I arbitrarily group the copy copy commands into groups of 10. This means I only ever pre-allocate up to 10 surface-backed 'sourceTextures' before committing the buffer. This seems to make the GPU a bit happier but the value of 10 seems rather arbitrary. Is there an optimum number here one could determine based on the hardware?

```
func renderInBatches() { 

  // Arbitrarily group surfaces into groups of 10.
  for group in visibleSurfaces(groupsOf: 10) {

    // Create a new command buffer and encoder for each group.
    let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()
    let blitEncoder = commandBuffer.makeBlitCommandEncoder()

    // Encode only up to 10 copy commands.
    for surface in group { 
      let surfaceTexture = makeTextureFromSurface()
      bitEncoder.copy(surfaceTexture, to: destinationTexture, slice:...)
    }
  
    blitEncoder.endEncoding()
    commandBuffer.commit()
    commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()
  }

  // Bind textures and issue draw calls using a render encoder.
}
```

**Attempt 3: One at a Time**

No code, but this option is just using the batch option above but with groups of 1. In effect, creating a new command buffer and blit encoded for every surface that needs to be copied to a texture. Initially this seemed incredibly wasteful, but now I realize that command buffers and encoders are quite lightweight. After all, you create new ones on each render pass anyways.

But is doing it once at a time under-utilizing the GPU? There's no dependencies between the copy operations.

**TL;DR**

If you have to issue a lot of `blit` copy commands, or scale commands using `MPS`, what is the most efficient and "correct" way of doing that?

*For now I'm building against macOS 11.0 and higher. The application is expected to run on any supported hardware.*

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely put as much work in a command buffers and encoders as possible.

In this case, you can have a single command buffer, which you populate with image filters first, and then do all the blits in a single blit command encoder.

On another note, you can also create an `MTLTexture` from `IOSurface`, so you won't have to blit if they have the same dimensions.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/1433378-newtexturewithdescriptor?language=objc

Comment: The issue with putting as much work as possible in a single buffer and encoder is that you end up allocating twice as much texture memory as you really need. (1x for the source and 1x for the destination.) Lower end devices seem to have issues with this and Xcode's insights lists a ton of warnings related to unused bound resources during a blit command. Which makes sense since only one source and one destination are used at any given time. The source textures are surface backed but need to get copied to a 2D Array because that's the only way to pass so many textures to the fragment shader.

Comment: Well, if the memory pressure is as high as you say that lower end devices have issues, then you will need to take the second approach from your question with a dynamic number of batches based on memory pressure. That's something you will probably need to either test per family of devices or just calculate heuristically. As for "so many textures" point: have you considered argument buffers?

Comment: I looked into Argument Buffers earlier but wasn't able to figure out how best to use them. Most Metal performance examples are about rendering large numbers of objects but with a small set of textures. I want to render a relatively small number of objects but with a large set of textures. For example, a 64k x 32k panorama with 1024px tiles would have almost 1000 IOSurfaces. A subset of these surfaces need to get dynamically rendered into textures as the user pans and zooms. If the pan or zoom is large, then a lot of surfaces need to get copied in one render pass.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to solve streaming problem. This might be a case for sparse textures like in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/modern_rendering_with_metal. Argument buffers are basically just buffers with pointers to textures and other buffer in them. You can bind them and just index into an array of textures and then you don’t have to use texture arrays

Comment: Not really streaming as the content on each IOSurface is relatively static. It represents decoded tiles of a potentially quite large image. I allocate a fixed amount of texture memory which is "roughly" enough to cover the maximum number of tiles that could be visible in the viewport at any one time. I could use a heap for that, but a 2D array texture has proved sufficient. What I remain unsure about is how to efficient copy tiles into that 2D array texture as the user pans and zooms. Sometimes I might only copy a few tiles, other times it could be dozens or more.